# Type of triangle problem of hackerrank SQl Advance select

Tags: mysql

Write a query identifying the type of each record in the TRIANGLES table using its three side lengths. Output one of the following statements for each record in the table:

Equilateral: It's a triangle with  sides of equal length.
Isosceles: It's a triangle with  sides of equal length.
Scalene: It's a triangle with  sides of differing lengths.
Not A Triangle: The given values of A, B, and C don't form a triangle.

Can someone plz point out what is wrong here :

```
select if(a=b=c,'Equilateral', 
      (select if(a=b or b=c or c=a,'Isosceles', select if( a+b Triangle','Scalene')))) 
       from triangles;
```

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a slight mistake on the definition of the Isosceles. Here's a fix to that:

```
SELECT
CASE WHEN A+B <= C OR A+C <= B OR B+C <= A  THEN 'Not A Triangle'
WHEN (A=B AND B!=C) OR (A=C AND C!=B) OR (B=C AND C!=A) THEN 'Isosceles'
WHEN (A=B AND B=C) THEN 'Equilateral'
ELSE 'Scalene'
END
FROM TRIANGLES
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a slight mistake with the Isosceles formula. Here's a quick fix

```
SELECT
CASE WHEN A+B <= C OR A+C <= B OR B+C <= A  THEN 'Not A Triangle'
WHEN (A=B AND B!=C) OR (A=C AND C!=B) OR (B=C AND C!=A) THEN 'Isosceles'
WHEN (A=B AND B=C) THEN 'Equilateral'
ELSE 'Scalene'
END
FROM TRIANGLES
```